# Why is Linux taking days to compile?

Tags: linux, yocto, lamp

I am new to Linux and trying to set up a LAMP Web Server for an industrial IOT-Device with following specifications:

Intel Quark X1020
1 GB DDR3-SDRAM

I am running an example image of Yocto Linux and started downloading the required packages as I have no package manager.

My problem is that compiling (make command) is so slow, it took couple of days to compile Apache and PHP. Now I am stuck on SQL, it is compiling since Friday (now 65 %).

Is this a normal behavior or what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Install Linux on your developer laptop. e.g. [Debian](http://debian.org/)

Comment: From your question it's not entirely clear whether you're trying to build all those on the IoT device or whether you're cross-compiling for it.  Either way - the process can be slow because it's a slow CPU, has little RAM, and, what no one so far has mentioned, the I/O subsystem isn't up to much.  Compiling a Linux kernel ~ 24 years ago was taking me days ...If you're trying to build on the IoT device: Pro-tip - get a cross-compiler toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

You have a relatively slow machine. You might be able to speed things up by using a cache like [`ccache`](https://ccache.dev/) but your slow machine is the big bottleneck.

If you are considering using this machine for a web & database server, I suspect that it will not be powerful enough to give you decent performance.

Answer (score 1):

Compile a new Yocto image on a faster, multi-threaded machine with much more RAM. Then flash that image on your Intel Quark machine.

If that is not possible, then you're stuck with this slow build unfortunately. I'm not even sure what you mean with "downloading the required packages" since installing packages from distros such as Ubuntu or Fedora is bound to fail at one point (different libc, different versions of libraries used for linking etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Thank God that it is still compiling and reached 65 % already !! Yocto required extensive CPU and Memory usage. Running yocto build on a single core(single thread) CPU with ONLY 1GB RAM is suicidal.

Get a PC with at least 2 cores (4 parallel thread) and 4 GB RAM :)

Comment: He does not seem to be building with Yocto, he's running an image that was built with Yocto

Comment: @JussiKukkonen Did you at least read the question ?

Comment: I did. It sounds like he was not building with Yocto, he was compiling on the target, i.e. manually downloading apache sources and running make on the quark. I was trying to say that it might not be useful to explain Yocto build requirements to someone who A) isn't building with Yocto and B) doesn't necessarily even know that's an option